# How do I pass back a specific variable of an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that repeats a dropdown. Each repeated div that holds the dropdown has a unique ID generated by the controller that I can reference.

How can I pass back the selected option for that specific dropdown? Right now, if one dropdown is selected, the value for selectedParameter.name changes for all dropdowns.

```
<div id="{{ mergeVar.name }}" class="alert {{ selectedParamClass }}" ng-repeat="mergeVar in mergeVars">
    <b>merge value: </b> {{mergeVar.name}}
    <div class="dropdown pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{selectedParameter.name || 'Match the Paramater'}}
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="param in availableParams">
          <a ng-click="selectParameter(parampass)">{{param.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
</div>

//controller.js

$scope.selectParameter = function(parampass) {
  console.log('parameter selected')
  $scope.selectedParameter = parampass
  $scope.selectedParamClass = 'alert-success'
}
```

Comment: I would assume you are doing this intead selectParameter(param) parampass is not declared anywhere?

Comment: please post some Fiddle or Plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead to affect only one instance of your object:

```
$scope.selectParameter = function(parampass) {
  console.log('parameter selected')  
  parampass.selectedParamClass = 'alert-success';
}
```

What you need is to add the property to the instance "row" object.

You can still store the selected object:

```
$scope.selectedParameter = parampass
```

But based on what I see in your code what you probably want do to is to use the `ng-class="selectedParamClass"` when an item is selected for the object selected.